# Jquery AJAX create select with parent-child functionality

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a data structure that goes like this:

```
Forum
   Topic
      Post
   Subscriptions
   Polls
Members
   Email
```

And so on. In reality there can be unlimited number of children. I want to create a jquery ajax call on page load, to get the outermost parents. Then, when I select a parent, another ajax call triggers, getting the children of this parent in ANOTHER select if they exist. Then, if i click on that child, another ajax call triggers, getting the children of the selected child, and so on and so forth. Then, when i click a different parent, all selects of previous parent dissapear.

How do i code this?

So far I have this: (parent_id=0 meaning: get outermost parents)

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'ajaxLoad.php?action=manage-permissions&mod=_get-entities&parent_id=0',
    success: function (response){
        $("#entities").html(response);
    }   
});    

//The below line does not work because the call is asynchronous and i prefer to keep it that way as its recommended
$(".parent_select").change(function(){
    alert("Chose");
});
```

UPDATE 1:

I have restructed the code so it looks like this:

```
var visible_entities = [];
var active_entity = 0;

function myCallback(result)
{
    if (result != "no_children")
    {
        $("#entities").append(result);      
    }

    $(".parent_select").change(function(){

        visible_entities.push( $(this).attr('rel') );

        foo(myCallback,$(this).val());

        for (i=0; i <= visible_entities.length; i++)
        {

        }

        active_entity = $(this).val();
    });    
}

function foo(callback,id)
{
    $.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'ajaxLoad.php?action=manage-permissions&mod=_get-entities&parent_id='+id,
        success: myCallback   
    });     
}

foo(myCallback,0);
```

Now I get every child in a new select tag. But when I change to another parent, the selects grow exponentially and still dont dissapear.

Comment: is this really an impossible task??

Comment: i still havent found a solution. unbelievable. i can swear i have seen such functionality somewhere. but im talking about UNLIMITED children, which is the main problem here.

Comment: anyone? this must be solvable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to understand your problem and so I found a solution, of course, because I do not have the client side I simulate it with an object client side.

```js
var JSONSampleMenu = {
  'Forum': {'Topic': {'Post': null}, 'Subscriptions': null, 'Polls': null},
  'Members': {'Email': null}
};
var urlSample = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([JSON.stringify(JSONSampleMenu, undefined, 4)], {type: 'application/json'}));


function myCallback(result, obj) {
  var mySubMenu = '<ul>';
  $.each(result, function(index, element) {
    mySubMenu += '<li class="menuItem">' + index + '</li>';
  });
  mySubMenu += '</ul>'
  obj.append(mySubMenu);
}
function getObject(response, menuName) {
  for(o in response) {
    if (o ==  menuName) {
      if (response[menuName])
        return response[menuName];
      else
        return null;
    }
  }
  for(o in response) {
    if (o != null) {
      var obj = getObject(response[o], menuName);
      if (obj != null) {
        return obj;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function toggleMenu(e, afterCreate) {
        var obj = $(e.target);
        if (obj.parent().attr('id') == 'menu') {
            if (afterCreate) {
                obj.siblings().children().toggle();
            } else {
                obj.children().toggle();
                obj.siblings().children().toggle();
            }
        } else {
            if (!afterCreate) {
                obj.children().toggle();
            }
        }
}

$(function () {
  $(document).on('click', ".menuItem", function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var obj = $(this);
    if (obj.children().length == 0) {
      var menuName = this.innerText;
      var menuDepth = obj.parents('#menu');
      $.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        url: urlSample,
        success: function (response) {
          var menuObj = getObject(response, menuName);
          if (menuObj != null) {
            myCallback(menuObj, obj);
            toggleMenu(e, true);
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      toggleMenu(e, false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<ul id="menu">
    <li class="menuItem">Forum</li>
    <li class="menuItem">Members</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: perfect, this works, however for example if i open Forum, and then open Members, I want Forum to close

Comment: you misunderstand me. the $(e.target).children().toggle(); line works if i for example open Forum. then Topics, Subscriptions and Polls show up. If i click on Forum again, they indeed do dissapear. BUT Forum and Members are SIBLINGS of each other, and opening one does not close the other if the other is opened.

Comment: also, as i forgot to mention, your approach actually does not solve my problem. the reason being is that i would prefer a select tag with options for each child. its not a menu. i need to be able to choose TOPIC as well as open it. a select tag with options allows me to do that, a ul with li's only allows me to get the children and choose the innermost child as my choice.

Comment: check out this url. only in this example ,you have a SET number of children. i want mine to be infinite http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

Comment: if its not too much trouble, i actually imagined this as a chain select as you call it. please imagine the following: Forum and Members are siblings. Therefore we have a select with two options: Forum and Members, each of their values are their id's in the database. Suppose you click on forum. Then a new select appears (it was not visible before), with Topics, Subscription and Polls as options. however its not required to choose them, because i want to make operations on Forum only. But if i choose Members, then the select with those three options is replaced by a select with children ofmember

Comment: did you have any luck?

Comment: @MikołajMarciniak No for the moment. Sorry

Comment: is it really this hard when children are potentially unlimited? i swear ive seen that functionality somewhere.